# mysqldump takes very long time to restore a backup, what's wrong?

Tags: mysql

The backup was made using phpMyAdmin with extended inserts enabled and is ~80MB in size. mysqldump does not complain restoring it (yet!) but it takes a long (>2 hours) time to do so. Insights ?

Very stupid of me, I was using a wrong syntax. Reading the manuals fixed it :-)

Comment: Try doing the whole restoration in transaction (so there is no need to flush every single line)

Comment: What's your mysql dumb command line?

Answer (score 0):

Try restoring by first deleting any index on that table.